# What interface does python use to implement sockets?

Tags: low-level, networks

When I programmed in python, I believe I interfaced with the transport layer using sockets.  If python was programmed by humans, they must have used an interface that was "lower" than sockets, to provide *us* with the interface to sockets.  I assume firewalls, also programmed by humans, use interfaces of lower layers in the same manner, so is there a way to access such lower layers, in terms of programming?

Comment: they are called system calls, and at some point code just sends bytes to the network card

Comment: @ratchetfreak Is there a language that allows a programmer to use such system calls?

Comment: And further down than that,  the network card makes a circuit with another electrical device (switch, router, another computer) and modulates the voltage on that circuit to transmit information.

Comment: Well python interpreter is doing exactly that, and it's written in C I believe.

Comment: And that means that when you make a call in python like select() to see if there's data on the socket waiting for you to handle it,  that is being executed as the select() system call.

Comment: So using select() *is* the system call?

Comment: No,  in a language like python as the below answer states,  the interpreter will make the system call if necessary (and if the language's select() actually maps to the syscall).  The language documentation should say how the interpreted version maps to the syscall.

Answer (score 1):

A language uses system calls to communicate with the lower layer

In an interpreted language it means that the script calls a "built in" function and then code outside the interpreter gets called (which then makes its own system calls).

In a compiled language the code signals a software interrupt which signals the OS that it needs something from outside using a predefined protocol.

The C standard is mostly convenience functions and wrappers around these system calls so the programmer doesn't need to remember how to signal each OS.

Answer (score 0):

To give some detail, here is Python's implementation of the `socket()` call.  That is, the following code is called when you do `x=socket.socket()` in Python, which initializes a `_socketobject` object for you.  It shows that in CPython, eventually it calls the good old C `socket()` function.

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/57130574d1e8/Modules/socketmodule.c#l3995